# SoapUI UTF-8 encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, soapui

I'm trying to make a 'DEL' REST request using Soapui Pro. One of the parameters includes a value containing '+' (which gets treated as SPACE if not UTF-8 encoded). Soapui doesn't seem to URL encode the request even though tried to re-enforce encoding in the REST request step.

Secondly, i tried to pass UTF-8 encoded value (encoded by a groovy step). But Soapui seems to, some how, automatically. decode the value before sending. Am i missing something here? Please help.

Sample request (RAW)
Sensitive data masked by XXXXX, YYYYY

DELETE https://XXXXXservices.com/XXXXX_services/ogw/emf/securityShare/888247189312/members?shareId=8882015810875&memberIds=XXXXX&auth-username=YYYYY&auth-nonce=XIX9UL9UBIE2L8K&auth-sharedkeyid=System&auth-expiresby=1414607713258&auth-algorithm=HMACSHA256&auth-signature=9JmAxG6rkqZe0Fu+zPQIh9Eh3tazDoE1YBZFxgIRLMc= HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: XXXXXservices.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

Comment: What version of SoapUI? There are some known problems with URL encoding: http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=23927

Comment: It's SoapUI Pro 5.0.0